# Repeated sampling according to a number in a row in R

Tags: r

I have a question and I will try to explain it as best as I can.

Let's say I have the following dataset let's call it extra_events:

```
   Year WEvents
     1       1
     2       3
     3       1
     4       2
     5       3
     6       0
     7       3
     8       0
     9       2
    10       3
```

and I have a different dataset let's call it weather_loss:

```
  Event Loss
    11    2
    21    3
    24    5
    27    8
    30   10
    34    7
    37    1
    41   14
    45   15
```

my goal is to randomly sample from weather_loss (event column) into each row from extra_events as many times as in the Wevents column (with replacement of course)

so for example the output would look like this:

```
   Year Wevents Sim1 Sim2 Sim3
     1       1   21   NA   NA
     2       3   24   30   37
     3       1   11   NA   NA
     4       2   45   41   NA
     5       3   30   34   37
     6       0   NA   NA   NA
     7       3   24   27   34
     8       0   NA   NA   NA
     9       2   37   45   NA
    10       3   11   21   30
```

This way I can see for each year how many events I have to sample and which events got sampled.

Could anyone help me out how to accomplish this. I don't need necessarily for there to be NA.

Comment: I'm confused. You want each row from extra_events with 3 different random Event values from weather_loss? If so, why the "NA"?

Comment: Also, what database are you using?

Comment: Ah, sorry, after re-reading, I understand the question now. Is there a cap to the value in WEvents, or is it arbitrary?

Comment: It is arbitrary, I am sampling from a Poisson distribution.for the WEvents, so it could go on forever.

Comment: In that case, the number of columns being returned are pretty dynamic, so would you be ok with each of the Sim values being a separate row, or maybe even a comma-delimited string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one option with `tidyverse` where we loop overr the 'WEvents', and `sample` the 'Event' based on the value in 'WEvents', return as a `list` column and then use `unnest_wider` from `purrr` to create multiple columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
extra_events %>% 
    mutate(Sim = map(WEvents, ~ sample(weather_loss$Event, .x) %>% 
                     as.list)) %>%
    unnest_wider(c(Sim)) %>%
    rename_at(vars(starts_with('..')), ~ str_c('Sim', seq_along(.)))
# A tibble: 10 x 5
#    Year WEvents  Sim1  Sim2  Sim3
#   <int>   <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1     1       1    37    NA    NA
# 2     2       3    24    37    41
# 3     3       1    30    NA    NA
# 4     4       2    34    30    NA
# 5     5       3    45    21    11
# 6     6       0    NA    NA    NA
# 7     7       3    37    11    34
# 8     8       0    NA    NA    NA
# 9     9       2    27    24    NA
#10    10       3    45    27    11
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
lst1 <- lapply(extra_events$WEvents, function(x) sample(weather_loss$Event, x))
mx <- max(lengths(lst1))    
extra_events[paste0("Sim_", seq_len(mx))] <- do.call(rbind, 
              lapply(lst1, `length<-`, mx))
```

#### data

```
extra_events <- structure(list(Year = 1:10, WEvents = c(1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 
3L, 0L, 2L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L
))

weather_loss <- structure(list(Event = c(11L, 21L, 24L, 27L, 30L, 34L, 37L, 41L, 
45L), Loss = c(2L, 3L, 5L, 8L, 10L, 7L, 1L, 14L, 15L)), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response. I tried using your first code but it is not recognizing unnest_wider, I do have purrr installed but it is not seeing the function.

Comment: @wdavid47 can you check your `packageVersion('purrr')`

Comment: @wdavid47 i am using `packageVersion('purrr')#
[1] ‘0.3.3’`

Comment: Oh it's version 0.3.0, I will try on my personal computer where I can have the newest R packages. I am on my work computer.

Comment: Thank you so much. I checked it on my personal computer and it worked.

Comment: I did, but it won't show up cause I have less than 15 reputation. Thanks again!